# Single instance controller in ASP .NET Core Web API REST

Tags: asp.net-core, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I am building a REST API using ASP .NET Core Web API and Entity Framework Core for connecting a SQL Server Database.

I have a controller which is handling some critical requests and I need these request to be handled synchronously because if two or more requests are handled at the same time, concurrence issues may cause big integrity problems in a database table.

Is this possible to achieve using ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: What to do if you start two Web API servers under Load Balancer?

Comment: I will not load balance this API, it will have just 2 or 3 requests per hour

Comment: Under Windows - [GlobalSemaphore](http://dotnetpattern.com/threading-semaphore). Also you can try lock on your database.

Comment: Do you need to wait on the result of these requests? otherwise you could use a BackgroundService [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and keep a queue of processing tasks. And you could still periodically check if a task is complete if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments and suggestions.

It may not be the best approach, but I finally ended up with:

In controller class, when a request is received I just insert the request body into a queue. There is a background thread reading this queue and processing each request body sequentially